# @ManyToMany NamingStrategy

Tags: java, jpa

There is the following case:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "another_table")
public class Table {
...
@javax.persistence.ManyToMany
    public java.util.Set<sth> getSth() {
        return this.sth;
    }
```

While making the query JPA thinks correcly that there is many to many table "another_table_sth" but expects to find column "table_id" in it as defined by the class name. However, there is actually a column another_table_id as defined by the @javax.persistence.Table annotation.

How to define this case in the naming strategy?

Comment: Try using `@JoinTable`? `@JoinTable(name = "my_table", schema = "my_schema", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "column_name", referencedColumnName = "name")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
`

Comment: Thanks but I am interested in using a way (NamingStrategy) to convert it automagically and not to use @JoinColumn annotations.

Comment: The JPA spec defines namings for tables/columns. See this reference for an abbreviated summary http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/datastore_identifiers.html  That is what you use for portability, or if you want to override it you do as advised above